# Помогите избавиться от неполадки в yum

Tags: php, linux, centos, ssh, pecl

пытаюсь установить модуль, выводятся строки ошибок

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 180

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 180

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 180

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 180

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 180

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 180

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 180

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 180

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 180

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 145

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 145

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 145

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 145

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 145

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 145

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 145

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 145

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 145

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 212

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 212

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 212

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 212

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 212

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 212

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 212

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 212

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 212

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 49

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 49

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 49

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 49

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 49

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 49

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 49

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 49

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 49

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259
XML Extension not found
```

погуглил, но не помогает

Comment: прикрепите отрывки кода из указанных файлов

Comment: @mix Это огромный установочные файлы от PEAR. Например в 259 строке он пытается открыть xml  файл....файлы скачаны yum от дистрибутив

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Помогите решить проблему с пакетами на сервере](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/585503/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5)

Comment: это видели http://serverfault.com/questions/589877/pecl-command-produces-long-list-of-errors ?

Comment: @KoVadim я не понимаю что там написано...нет дело не с английским...просто отвечающий там не дает кокретную инструкцию..а советует лазить туда, просмотреть то се и тд...не понимаю я, не доходит...не четко..поэтому решил сам вопрос задать

Comment: @HasanaghaAliyev, пожалуйста, [придерживайтесь тона конструктивной профессиональной дискуссии](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) и правил сообщества.